# I can open SqlConnection once, but I can't do it again

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

My program runs, and it initially connects to the database successfully. I can run queries and everything works fine. However, I cant seem to disconnect and reconnect to the database. The output says: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll" Here is my connection method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class TCNInteraction
    {
        static string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TCN;Trusted_Connection=true";
        Button theButton;
        TextBox theTextBox;
        bool currentlyConnectedToADatabase = false;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        /*
         *Uses the already existing SQL connection string and attempts to establish a connection 
         */
        public bool connectToDatabase(Button inputButton, TextBox inputDatabaseBox)
        {
            theButton = inputButton;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to open connection...");
                if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("About to open the connection");
                    cnn.Open();
                }
                Console.Write("I opened the connection!");
                currentlyConnectedToADatabase = true;
                displayRowsOfDatabase(inputDatabaseBox);
                theButton.Text = "Connected";
                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }

        }

        private void displayRowsOfDatabase(TextBox inputDatabaseBox)
        {

            theTextBox = inputDatabaseBox;
            using (cnn)
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SomeNumber,SomeText, AnotherNumber FROM tcn.Demo;", cnn);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string printString = int.Parse(reader["SomeNumber"].ToString()) + " " + reader["SomeText"].ToString() + " " + int.Parse(reader["AnotherNumber"].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
                        theTextBox.Text += printString;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }


        public void disconnectFromDatabase()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Disconnected from Database");
            cnn.Close();
            theButton.Text = "Connect to Database";
            //theTextBox.Text = "";
            currentlyConnectedToADatabase = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The connection is never closed. Include a `finally` block that closes the connection. This will ensure it is closed even if the `catch` block is executed. Also, I would include variable `bool successful = false`, and set it `true` in the `try` block, `false` in the `catch`, and return `successful` instead of true. Your method will always return `true` as you have it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try/catch` block is not closing your connection. Give the responsibility to close the connection to the `finally` block. It will close the connection even if any exception occurs in the program. Try as following...

```
public bool connectToDatabase(Button inputButton, TextBox inputDatabaseBox)
{
    theButton = inputButton;
    try
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to open connection...");

            //THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK THE SECOND TIME
            if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cnn.Open();
            }
            Console.Write("I opened the connection!");
            currentlyConnectedToADatabase = true;
            displayRowsOfDatabase(inputDatabaseBox);
            theButton.Text = "Connected";
            return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }

}
public void disconnectFromDatabase()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Disconnected from Database");
        if(cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
        theButton.Text = "Connect to Database";
        //theTextBox.Text = "";
        currentlyConnectedToADatabase = false;
    }
```

Comment: tried your code, it still comes up with the same error, any ideas? I have added the rest of my code as that could be the problem

Comment: from where are you firing `disconnectFromDatabase` method?

Comment: the method is only called when the button on the Form is pressed

Comment: @EquityEcho rearrange your `disconnectFromDatabase` as mentioned in the edited answer

Comment: that worked! can you explain why though? Was i trying to close a connection that was already closed?

Answer (score 2):

Include a `finally` block in your `try/catch` to close the connection. Also, I would advise using a `bool` variable to determine success of connection.

```
public bool connectToDatabase(Button inputButton, TextBox inputDatabaseBox)
{
    bool status = false;

    theButton = inputButton;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to open connection...");

        //THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK THE SECOND TIME
        if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnn.Open();
        }

        Console.Write("I opened the connection!");
        currentlyConnectedToADatabase = true;
        displayRowsOfDatabase(inputDatabaseBox);
        theButton.Text = "Connected";

        status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: tried your code, it still comes up with the same error, any ideas? I have added the rest of my code as that could be the problem

Comment: it actually just throws the exception from the catch block in the connectToDatabase(). However, if I comment out the displayRowsOfDatabase(inputDatabaseBox), it appears that it successfully connects. I think there is something in the displayRowsOfDatabase() that is trying to open something that is already open perhaps. I just can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: I would step thru `displayRowsOfDatabase()` to find exactly where the problem is happening. Put a breakpoint at the opening bracket and press F11 (default) to step line by line. You might also put a `try/catch` around the code as well.

Comment: TestWell! Thanks for the help! I found that the problem was actually my disconnect method. Much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your if statement to be

```
        //THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK THE SECOND TIME
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnn.Close();
            cnn.Open();
        }
```

With the != you are only calling the cnn.Close() if the connection is not open.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to close the closed connection which is throwing exception:

```
if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   cnn.Close();
}
cnn.Open();
```

Try above to close the connection if its already opened and then open it up